# Repeat Opportunity related list in my Contact object

Tags: custom-object, opportunity, standard-objects, contact, related-list

I am editing the page layout for my Contact object and noticed that there are two related lists for Opportunities. Can anyone explain why this is? The object has the same available fields to display even though there are different fields currently displaying:

[image]

Comment: Do you have [Person Accounts](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_person.htm&language=en_US) in this org?

Comment: custom contact lookup field on opportunity ?

Answer (score 3):

You have two objects that link from opportunities to contacts. By default, the first is the Opportunity Contact Role related list. The second one would, by necessity, be a custom field that also links opportunity to contact, and happens to have the same related list name. Look for a Lookup(Contact) field under Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Fields, and you should find that the field's related list name is "Opportunities", which would be the default name for the related list when creating it in the UI.